# Symfony2 treeBuilder new root item

Tags: symfony, symfony-2.4

I have created a new root in my treeBuilder:

```php
class Configuration implements ConfigurationInterface
{
    public function getConfigTreeBuilder()
    {
        $apiNode = $treeBuilder->root('nieuwname');
        $apiNode
            ->children()
                ->scalarNode('test')
                ->isRequired()
            ->end();
    }
}
```

Then I get the next exception:

> `The child node "test" at path "nieuwname" must be configured.`

Oké sounds good.

```yaml
# config.yml
nieuwname:
    test: "test"
```

And then I get a exception:

> `There is no extension able to load the configuration for "nieuwname"`

What do I do wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to override the Extension alias with what you have defined as your root tree.

```
namespace Your\BundleNameBundle\DependencyInjection;

class YourBundleNameExtension implements ExtensionInterface
{
    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    public function getAlias()
    {
        return 'nieuwname';
    }
}
```

**or** change the root tree name to match the alias naming convention, which tends to be an inflection of your bundle name to lowercase and underscores.

So a bundle called `MyWebsiteBundle` would have the alias `my_website`

```
$apiNode = $treeBuilder->root('your_bundle_name');
```

Comment: Well, this isn't the solution for my problem, because this will allow you to add 1 alias, but what if I want to add later another root item: `anotherNewName`.

Comment: The extension is supposed load the configuration for the bundle, therefore you can only have one. If you want two definitions then they should be children of the root node, that should ideally be the underscored name of your bundle. [You can see the method responsible for this on Github](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/Bundle/Bundle.php#L72)

Comment: That said you can load more than one configuration but it won't be straightforward as it will involve overriding a lot the behaviour of the `Bundle` and `Extension` classes. [This article](http://php-and-symfony.matthiasnoback.nl/2013/10/symfony2-some-things-i-dont-like-about-bundles/) might help

Comment: Oke, so the conclusion is I can't create a "new" root and have to stick to the name or alias of my bundle. (like I already had that as temp solution). What to do with this stackoverflow issue? Because I don't want an alias but your comment made clear its not possible what I want.

Answer (score 0):

It is because the alias in your extension class is not exactly the same. Symfony2 detects the alias using the naming convention (e.g. a bundle named MyCustomAPIBundle will have my_custom_a_p_i alias). If you change it in your configuration class, you will have such an exception.

Look at [this article](http://php-and-symfony.matthiasnoback.nl/2013/10/symfony2-some-things-i-dont-like-about-bundles/) to know you to use a custom alias and avoid repeated code lines.

Comment: Well, this isn't the solution for my problem, because this will allow you to add 1 alias, but what if I want to add later another root item: `anotherNewName`.

Comment: Please can you post or paste a link of your Configuration et Extension classes ?

Comment: follow the comments in the previous answer.